# ¿Cómo "sacar" datos correctamente dentro de API fetch javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una función donde según unas condiciones me llene un `array`

aquí un ejemplo bien sencillo del problema (el código original es extenso, pero es algo similar a este):

```
function enviadodato() {
var id = 1
var condicion;

var elementos = new Array();

  if (condicion == true) {
    fetch('/api/datos/' + id).then((response) => response.json()).then((datos) => {
        datos.forEach(element => {
            elementos.push(Number(element.valores))
        });
    });
    // console.log(elementos)
  } else {
    elementos.push(0)
  }
  console.log(elementos)
}
```

> entonces, el problema es que a lo que reviso la consola, si me devuelve los datos, pero me lo devuelve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y a lo que intento "usar" el `array` no me genera nada, es como si no tuviera ningún valor.

cómo puedo obtener los datos correctamente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el `console.log` se ejecuta antes que la `Promise` se resuelva.

Para ver los datos reales una vez se ha completado la *request* al servidor, debes fijarte dentro del `then` que se ejecutará una vez esté la *request* completada.

```
function enviadodato() {
  const id = 1;
  const condition = true;
  const elements = [];

  if (condition) {
    fetch(`/api/datos/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        elements = data.map(element => Number(element.valores));

        // Aquí es donde el array elements
        // Está procesado
        console.log(elements);
      });
  } else {
    elements.push(0);
  }

  // Se ejecuta inmediatamente
  console.log(elements);
}
```

Si lo que necesitas es que la función devuelva ese *array* de `elements`, deberás hacer `return` de una `Promise` que resuelva ese mismo *array* procesado.

```
const enviadodato = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ..

    if (condition) {
      fetch(`/api/datos/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          elements = data.map(element => Number(element.valores));

          // Aquí es donde el array elements
          // Está procesado
          console.log(elements);
          // Resolvemos la Promise con el array 
          // elements ya procesado
          resolve(elements);
        })
        // Capturamos el error en caso de haber uno
        .catch(reject);
    } else {
      elements.push(0);
      // También resolvemos la Promise
      // en este caso.
      resolve(elements);
    }
  });
```

Además, también se puede refactorizar para hacerla `async/await` y leerla de forma más simple.

```
const send = async () => {
  // ...

  if (condition) {
    const response = await fetch(`...`);
    const data = await response.json();
    elements = data.map(element => Number(element.valores));
  } else {
    elements.push(0);
  }

  // Elements ya ha sido procesado
  console.log(elements);
  return elements;
}
```

Por último, sólo habría que esperar a la resolución de la promise que devuelve la función `enviadodato`.

```
enviadodato()
  .then(elementos => {
    // ...
  });
```

**Nota**
He substituido el código de

```
datos.forEach(element => {
    elementos.push(Number(element.valores))
});
```

... por el `map` porque hace básicamente lo mismo, sólo eso.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Excelente!, +1.

Comment: VRoxa, Hola gracias por responder, mire la única forma con la cual me hace lo que necesito en esa función es con la ultima. pero no funciona con `map()` tuve que usar  `forEach`, ahora el éxito de eso era que ese `array` lo termino usando en otra función, y me devuelve una promesa. https://prnt.sc/sqvhtl entonces, nunca he usado eso y no se como utilizarlo, me podrias aclarar un poco como puedo recorrer esa promesa para poder usarla ? gracias.

Comment: Como comenté en la respuesta, dado que ahora la función `enviadodato` devuelve una `Promise`, debes esperar a que ésta se resuelva para poder obtener el *array* de `elementos`. Fíjate cómo lo puse justo antes de la **Nota**

Comment: Voy a resumir un poco antes de la pregunta clave que probablemente todo el mundo se hace antes de conocer las promises xd, **no puedes sacar valores directamente de una promise**, estos quedan "encarcelados" por decirlo de alguna manera dentro del cuerpo de sus metodos then o catch, dependiendo de si la respuesta es un valor o un error, y no, no hay forma de sacar el valor de una Promise directamente para asignarla a algo, simplemente hay que limitarse a usar .then y .catch, o en casos mas concretos puedes usar await. de todas maneras en .then siempre tendras disponibles los datos.

Comment: como comentario el map() solo funcionara cuando tengas seguro que tienes mas de 1 dato a mapear, sino da error.

Comment: Se está trabajando con APIs, por lo que podemos dar por supuesto que la respuesta a ese *endpoint* va a ser siempre un *array*. En una API bien diseñada, si no hay datos, este *endpoint* debería devolver un *array* vacío (para prevenir *crashes*) y `map` funciona perfectamente sobre un *array* vacío, devolviendo otro *array* vacío. En cualquier caso, se podría hacer un *truth assertion* sobre la respuesta del servidor, aunque debería ser antes de invocar la función `json`; es decir, ese `map` nunca va a fallar ya que si se llega a él, es que existe un *array* a mapear, vacío o no.

Comment: @VRoxa justo iba a decir lo mismo VRoxa, eso es cierto.