# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un return en javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una funcion que dentro guardo una api, lo que hago es retornar lo que obtengo de la api y con otra funcion tomar ese valor y asi poder usarlo, pero siempre me sale indefinido.

```
function api(){
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        return data.results
    })
}

function obtener(){
  let resultado=api()
  console.log(resultado); //aqui me sale indefinido
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo "sacar" datos correctamente dentro de API fetch javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360856/c%c3%b3mo-sacar-datos-correctamente-dentro-de-api-fetch-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

El método fetch devuelve una promesa, en el modo que lo estás implementando `console.log(resultado)` devuelve indefinido porque aún no ha sido resuelta la solicitud. Prueba de la siguiente forma, saludos.

```js
const api = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.results;
}

const obtener = async () => {
  const resultado = await api();
  console.log(resultado);
}

obtener();
```